# Getting an option value always return 'null'

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons

I have stuck with the following situation. Whenever I try to get an option value, it returns null.

Here is the code fragment:

```
    public static Options configureOptions() {      
    Option groupOption = Option.builder("g")
            .longOpt("group")
            .required(false)
            .desc("The group of the user.")
            .build();
    Options allOptions = new Options();
    allOptions.addOption(taskOption);

    return allOptions;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    Options options = configureOptions();
    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    CommandLine commands = parser.parse(options, args);
    if (commands.hasOption("group")) {
        System.out.println("group: " + commands.getOptionValue("group"));
    }
}
```

And running with option **-g staff** then the output is ALWAYS `null`.

`java -classpath rsa-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;c:\Users\user.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.3.1\commons-cli-1.3.1.jar Main -g staff`

Comment: What does `-g staff` do other than causing the output to be null?

Comment: Read the javadoc: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/index.html: *opt - **Short** name of the option*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `Option.Builder`, you need to specify that your `groupOption` has an argument by using `hasArg()`.

```
Option groupOption = Option.builder("g")
            .longOpt("group")
            .required(false)
            .desc("The group of the user.")
            .hasArg() // This option has an argument.
            .build();
```

Javadoc:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.Builder.html#hasArg--

Usage/Examples:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html

Comment: This fix the problem. :)